# How to remove duplicate matplotlib plot

Tags: python, tensorflow, matplotlib, visualization

I am trying to develop a small feature that plots dynamically the loss or accuracy during the training of a Tensorflow model. I basically plot the history of accuracies at the end of each batch processing for each epoch (the code still needs some corrections but it works correctly for now).

I have a small problem, as I run the following code in a jupyter notebook cell. I have the desired behavior, with a plot that evolves dynamically. However at the end of the training the final plot is duplicated for some reason and I can't figure out why it is the case.

```
from IPython.display import display, clear_output
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


class CustomCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_train_begin(self, logs=None):
        self.epoch = 0  # Initialize the epoch counter
        self.accuracies = []
        self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots()
        self.line, = self.ax.plot([], [])
        self.ax.set_xlim(0, 30)
        self.ax.set_ylim(0, 1)
        self.displayed = False
        display(self.fig)
    
    def on_epoch_begin(self, epoch, logs=None):
        self.epoch = epoch  # Update the current epoch at the beginning of each epoch

    def on_train_batch_end(self, batch, logs=None):
        accuracy = logs['accuracy']
        self.accuracies.append(accuracy)
        self.line.set_data(range(1, len(self.accuracies) + 1), self.accuracies)
        self.ax.relim()
        self.ax.autoscale_view()
        clear_output(wait=True)
        display(self.fig)


custom_callback = CustomCallback()

model = Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=16, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.35))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, activation='tanh'))

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(), loss="binary_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])

X = np.random.randn(10**2, 10**4)
y = np.random.randint(2, size=10**2)

abc = model.fit(X, y, epochs=7, batch_size=32, validation_split=0.025, verbose=False, callbacks=[custom_callback])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because jupyter notebook already shows a figure inline, so calls to `display()` is duplicating it. For example, the following code shows the same line plot twice in jupyter notebook.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(range(3))
display(fig)
```

To turn off the interactive mode, call `plt.ioff()` right after matplotlib import. Alternatively, you can also close the figure at the end of training by including the following method to the class.

```py
    def on_train_end(self, logs=None):
        plt.close(self.fig)
```